# VBA to get address from Google result

Tags: excel, vba

I have found this code which is returning the address of the first result in Google search page.

I need a similar or new code to get the address of the result which contains a specific website. For example if the third result leads to "www.example.com/address", I need to get this value back into Excel ("www.example.com/address").

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


    str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
    str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit your search to only that site and then you can still take the first result.

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i,1) & "+site%3Aexample.com" & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
```

If you also want to return which position the link is in in the list, you need to replace these two lines

```
'Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
'Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)
```

with

```
Set hHeadElems = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")

For j = 0 To hHeadElems.Length
    lCnt = lCnt + 1
    Set objH3 = hHeadElems(j)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)

    If link.href Like "http://www.w3schools.com*" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
```

That loops through all the h3 elements until it finds a link that matches a certain domain (w3schools in this example). The lCnt variable will be its position in the list and you can return it like

```
Cells(i, 4) = lCnt
```

You'll need to check that it actually found something by checking if `link Is Nothing`.

Comment: But in this case I will not get the real position in the organic results, I will always get the first place

Comment: Do you want URL, the position, or both?

Comment: I need both the url and position